# How can I make it jump to "a name" part when a link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code automatically inserts value to input field class name `chat_box` when a link is clicked. 
Now, it works completely fine.

I want to add one more action here.
I want it to jump to `chat_box` part when a link is clicked.

How can I do that?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
     $(document).on('click', 'a#username', function()  {
         $(".chat_box#body_input").val($(this).attr('value'));
     });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollIntoView)

```
$(".chat_box#body_input").val($(this).attr('value'))[0].scrollIntoView();
```

**Changed requirement:**
In case you need to jump 20px above of `chat_box` and focus to the input field, try this:

```
var input = $(".chat_box#body_input");
input.val($(this).attr('value'));
$(document).scrollTop(input.offset().top - 20);
input.focus();
```

Comment: @MKK: this is the simplest and easiest way to deal with your original requirement. In case you need to jump 20px above of chat_bot, Palash Mondal's answer meets that requirement

Comment: @MKK: after scrolling like Palash Mondal's answer, use focus() after that

Comment: Now it won't input anything, and it won't jump

Comment: $(document).on('click', 'a#username', function()  {
            $(".chat_box#body_input").val($(this).attr('value'));

var input = $(".chat_box#body_input");
input.val(this.value);
$(document).scrollTop(input .offset().top - 20);
input.focus();

        });

Comment: @MKK: the problem is input.val(this.value); and you have duplicated code $(".chat_box#body_input").val($(this).attr('value')); var input = $(".chat_box#body_input"); input.val(this.value);. Check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a#username', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // Cancel the default action (navigation) of the click
    var $elem = $(".chat_box#body_input");
    $elem.val(this.value);
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $elem.offset().top - 20
    }, 'slow');
});
```

Comment: Thanks!! Is it possible to make it without smooth moving animation? I don't want animation

Comment: @MKK: if you don't need animation, just call $('html, body').scrollTop($elem.offset().top - 20)

Comment: @PalashMondal It still won't input into `chat box` why?